# How to write a resource collection dependency

Tags: chef-infra

In a recipe `nginx` I use a `service` resource.

```
service 'nginx' do
  supports status: true, restart: true, reload: true
  action [:enable, :start]
end
```

And in another recipe `foo`, `notifies :reload, 'service[nginx]'` is used.

When I run the both recipes or only `nginx`, it works fine.
But when only `foo` is in a `run_list`, it fails with error `service[nginx] cannot be found in the resource collection.`

Currently I'm using this command when I want to run only `foo`.

```
knife solo cook my_server --override-runlist "nginx,foo`
```

I added `depends 'nginx'` to `foo/metadate.rb`, but it doesn't solve the problem.

How can I specify a dependency like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need both the `depends` in the metadata and `include_recipe 'nginx'` at the top of `foo/recipes/default.rb`. You cannot just run `recipe[foo::default]` as it has a hard dep on that service resource existing.

This would be a good example of why override run lists are a bit hard to work with and kind of break down when you write complex code. Another option would be a bit more complex, in the foo recipe check if the resource exists in the collection and create a stub (which does nothing) if it doesn't, but that is outside of the scope of what I would want to describe if you don't know Chef's internals super well.

Comment: I do think giving the method to define a `action :nothing` service resource after a test on the resource collection would be good in this answer, it may help future readers with the same problem. (upvoted anyway, but giving my point of view)

Comment: @Tensibai A few issues, action nothing wouldn't be enough. Second, querying the resource collection is tricky depending on context. Third, any such solution would be very very brittle and someone trying to copy off SO is probably going to end up more broken than helped.